# What is a running CRC?

Tags: crc, crc32

I have searched and am not able to find information on what it is and how it is computed.

---

I have no idea why the question has been negative voted. Is it not clear and programming related? Or should I have asked:

```
# Or you can compute the running CRC:
$crc = 0;
$crc = Archive::Zip::computeCRC32( 'abcdef', $crc );
$crc = Archive::Zip::computeCRC32( 'ghijkl', $crc );
```

What exactly happens here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, basically it's just a [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). The word *running* would mean that you are supposed to calculate it on-the-fly, as the data is incoming, or that you are doing a cumulative calculation (which is the way CRC is implemented).

You have a good example:

```
  # Or you can compute the running CRC:
  $crc = 0;
  $crc = Archive::Zip::computeCRC32( 'abcdef', $crc );
  $crc = Archive::Zip::computeCRC32( 'ghijkl', $crc );
```

Note how the `$crc` variable is set to 0 at the beginning, and the updated **twice**. The algorithm for CRC calculation uses the previously calculated CRC value and **updates** it. That is why it is sometimes called *running CRC*.

From your code I presume you already have an implementation, if not, simply google for CRC32.